# How can I use a variable within a ".." range, as in {1..${num_lanes}}?

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

If I print out a loop with fixed values like so:

```
for i in L0{1..4}
do
    echo $i
done
```

I get the desired output:

```
L01
L02
L03
L04
```

However, if I try to use a variable:

```
for i in L0{1..${num_lanes}}
do
    echo $i
done
```

I get:

```
L0{1..4}
```

How can I use a variable within curly braces?

Comment: When you run `sh`, that causes your shebang specifying bash to be ignored. If you want your code to run with bash, you need to run bash, not sh.

Comment: And brace expansion has never worked with variables even in bash. Braces get expanded **before** variables are expanded, so you can't use a variable to determine what brace expansion will do.

Comment: The answer is "you can't" (without insecure dirty hacks). Bash doesn't support it.

Comment: See also [BashPitfalls #33](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D)

Comment: `for ((i=1; i<=num_lanes; i++)); do echo "L0$i"; done`

Comment: Provided that you know for sure that `num_lanes` contains a number, `for i in $(eval "echo L0{1..$num_lanes}");` should do, but a counting loop, as Charles Duffy suggests, is IMO clearer.

Comment: Brace expansion happens before any other expansion (like parameter expansion, as you would need here); see 4th para in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)